# How can I make variable global in View?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to define below code as a global variable in the View and then I could use that value in my separate JS code. I don't know how to do this, I tried various things.

```
<td class="choice">

       @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ManualDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker" }) //I want this @Html... to be global and available in .js file
</td>
```

So this part of my View should be declared somewhere on the top of partial View? In curly brackets?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "myTitle";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var globalVar = "@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ManualDate, new { @type = 'date', @class = 'form-control datepicker' })";

}
```

I refer to it in .js file but it doesn't work properly (in 'choice' data field string is showed instead of razor element):

```
finalChoice.innerHTML = '@Model.globalVar'
```

Comment: The browser do not understand razor syntax. What you can do in Javascript is getting access to the `input` element by id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The razor syntax like  `@Html.TextBoxFor`  and `@Model` can only be parsed by the server, not JavaScript. Using variables in `@{//...}` will be parsed as a string. The JavaScript file in the parent page can directly call the elements in the partial view.

`@Html.TextBoxFor` can be placed in the view. But if you don’t want to show it in the view, please set its style to hide. Then you can get this element via its id.

In _part.cshtml(partial view)

```
<div id="part">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.ManualDate, new { @type = "date", @class = 
  "form-control datepicker" })
</div>
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ere3.png)

Comment: I have such a code in my View:               ```<td class="choice">

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ManualDate, new { @type = "date", @class = 
  "form-control datepicker" })
                </td>``` and see id as you showed. But question is can I refer to this id from .js file?

Comment: Yes, .js file can refer to this id.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, great, thanks! It's very interesting that id is added automatically to razor instructions like that